# Getting stuck in usleep(1.)

Tags: c, gcc, c99

My program gets stuck in the simple call `usleep(1.);`. How can that be? What should I look out for?

**Edit:**

To make things even more confusing, it only gets stuck if I call rand() before:

```
rand();
usleep(1.);
```

Both calls individually are just fine.

**Edit 2:**

Here is a minimal example that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        printf("Calling rand() and then usleep(1) on pid %d \n",getpid());
        rand();
        usleep(1);
        printf("Finished.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

This one also works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        printf("Calling usleep(1.) on pid %d \n",getpid());
        usleep(1.);
        printf("Finished.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

However, this one does not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        printf("Calling rand() and then usleep(1.) on pid %d \n",getpid());
        rand();
        usleep(1.);
        printf("Finished.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I compile these with gcc version 4.4.6 using the command `gcc -std=c99 main.c`. Is the option `-std=c99` the problem? But I still don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck inside `usleep`? Could you please edit your question to include some more context and code, like if the `usleep` is inside a loop.

Comment: I run a debugger and yes, it's stuck in usleep(), or, to be precise, in the internal function __nanosleep_nocancel(). It's not inside a loop.

Comment: I think you have found a bug. Those interesting in such things would like to see the assembly code for that, I am sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `usleep()` with a `double` value, while it's specified to take an unsigned integer of type `useconds_t` with limited range. See [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep).

Perhaps the conversion fails, on your platform. Try removing the period, and just call it with `1`.

Don't introduce casts, it's best to not mention the `useconds_t` type.

Also, note that this function is obsolete, new POSIX code should use `nanosleep()` instead.

**UPDATE** By the way, the manual page linked above also seems to imply that you should `#define` the proper symbols as listed before `#include <unistd.h>`, to get this function. You should try that, if you're not getting the prototype the argument will not be automatically converted from `double`. The (ignored) return value from `rand()` might also be in some register or on the stack, causing things to further change in that case.

Comment: For some reason this is important, but I'm still confused why it sometimes works and sometimes not. I edited the answer to clarify that.

Comment: That's the right answer! Adding, for example, `#define __USE_BSD` before the include statement does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure I just ran into this problem, although, as noted by others, it doesn't occur reliably, so it's difficult to determine if the fix is a fix. 

Still, it doesn't really make sense why casting solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

from the man page of usleep http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/usleep/, the input parameter of `usleep` is `useconds_t` and  not `float` as indicated in your code

Comment: The compiler should be able to do an implicit type cast without a problem.

Comment: For some reason this does the trick! However, I agree with @JoachimPileborg that this should not make a difference. It also doesn't explain the erratic dependance on the `rand()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things.

1. There's nothing special about `rand();` `printf` will do it too. The following also shows this behavior (it hangs after saying "Starting"), but if the first `printf()` is commented out, the program completes.

   ```
   include <stdio.h>
   include <unistd.h>

   void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
       printf ("Starting\n"); 
       usleep(10.1);
       printf("Finished.\n");
   }
   ```
2. If you compile with `-std=gnu89` (or gnu99) rather than `-std=c89` (or c99), your program always works.
3. Various permutations of -o0 to -o3 make no difference.
4. `usleep` needs an int, not a float. If you explicitly cast it, i.e. `usleep((int)10.1)`, the program doesn't hang.
5. Turning on the warnings (-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion) complains about an implicit declaration of `usleep`.